# Delegate not work

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, delegates

I' ve this swift code where I've create a delegate but this not work correctly. I not understand where I wrong

```
protocol MenuDelegate {
    func upateUserProfileImage()
}

// Userprofile view
class UserProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    var delegate : MenuDelegate?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate?.upateUserProfileImage()
    }

}

class MenuViewController: UIViewController, MenuDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func upateUserProfileImage()  {
        print("Work!")
    }
}
```

Thanks for help!!

Comment: And where is set the delegate?

Answer (score 3):

The reason it is not called is because, `self.delegate` is nil, you would need to set the delegate for instance if you was presenting the `UserProfileViewController` then you would set the delegate then e.g.

```
func openUserProfileViewController() {
    let userProfileViewController = UserProfileViewController()
    userProfileViewController.delegate = self
    present....
}
```

In this example now `self.delegate` in `UserProfileViewController` is not nil and thus will call back to your VC

Answer (score 0):

your delegate is never setted in your bunch of code.

you may see that by replacing

```
self.delegate?.upateUserProfileImage()
```

by

```
guard let del = self.delegate else {
print("delegate is not setted - nil value")
}

del.upateUserProfileImage()
```

You should set your delegate like this where you push the `UserProfileViewController`:

```
let userProfile: UserProfileViewController = UserProfileViewController() // or your instance already init
userProfile.delegate = MenuViewController() // or the instance already init somewhere in your code
```

Bonus: Be careful of your retain cycle between `UserProfileViewController` and the delegate `MenuViewController`, you should use a `weak` var :

```
class UserProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate : MenuDelegate?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate?.upateUserProfileImage()
    }

}
```

Without it, you may have memory leaks / zombies object which will be never released

Comment: Hi lngdt!! thanks for reply, can you provide the example in my init function please?

Comment: @StefanoToppi i can't because i don't know your workflow or how you init your object in your code. But focus your attention about "where to set my delegate in my code" I suggest you to check where you init both `MenuVC` and `UserProfileVC` and make the match here

Comment: ok infact i dont understand this step 
let userProfile: UserProfileViewController = UserProfileViewController() // or your instance already init
userProfile.delegate = MenuViewController() // or the instance already init somewhere in your code
and where use userProfile

Comment: you have to link/bind your menuViewController into your UserProfileViewController. CHeck your code where you init your `UserProfileViewController ` by code or by segue. Both case you have to, before you `UserProfileViewController ` is presented/pushed to set its delegate

Comment: I've add a overraide function prepare and  now work, the problem is that, I use teodorpatras/SideMenuController and i use his segue sideMenuController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueUserProfile", sender: nil)